# How to does rounding off binary number works?

Tags: binary, floating-point, precision, binary-data

I am currently learning floating points and my question is:

if I have a number like 0.01 and I want to round it off then I have 0.1

but if I have a number , 0.000000001, does that mean I have 0.1 as well or 0.0?

Comment: `0.01` *cannot* be rounded *off* to `0.1`.

Comment: It's just like in decimal: 0.01 is exactly half of 0.1, i.e. 0.5(dec). So when rounding, 0.01 gets rounded *up* to 0.1. `0.001` is 1/4 of `0.1`, i.e. 0.25(dec) and hence will be rounded *off* to `0.0`.